# CSS to access QHeaderView item columns to set background-image, or set large icon to QHeaderView

Tags: css, qt, qt5, qheaderview

I need CSS access to all columns of the QHeaderView
 to set backround image to the first column i can access via:

```
QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first{

    background-image: url(:/Icons/icon_1.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #4B4B4B;
}
```

to the last column i can access via:

```
QHeaderView::section:horizontal:last{

    background-image: url(:/Icons/icon_5.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #4B4B4B;
}
```

Any idea how can i get second third... etc columns? to set background image or set Large Icon to QHeaderView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All i wanted was to set large icons to QHeaderView but with css i can access just to first and last item, i found a solution to change size of QHeaderView items icons via QProxyStyle class and i will share my solution here:

All you need to to is to inherit QProxyStyle class to your own class override the drawControl method and setStyle to your TreeView

```
   HeaderStyle* style= new HeaderStyle();
    treeVew->header()->setStyle(style);
```

you can use

```
 Model->horizontalHeaderItem(0)->setIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/icon_1.png"));
```

to set your Icons

```
class HeaderStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    void drawControl(ControlElement element,const QStyleOption * option, QPainter * painter, const QWidget * widget = 0) const
    {
        if (element == CE_HeaderLabel) {

            QStyleOptionHeader *op = (QStyleOptionHeader *) option;

            QIcon icon = qvariant_cast<QIcon>(op->icon);
            QSize iconsize(120,120);

            QRect iconRect = op->rect;
            QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(iconsize.width(),iconsize.height());


            painter->drawPixmap(QPoint(iconRect.left() + 5, iconRect.top()+ 5), pixmap);

            return;
        }
        QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
    }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

Im doing this in my application by simply using:

```
QHeaderView::section {
    /* MY CSS STUFF HERE */
}
```

This styles all of them

Comment: I dont need to style all of them i need to set specific  background-image for each column that is the point here....

Comment: oh right ok should have mentioned that ill take a look